# How to upgrade pip to pip3 and switch from python 2.7 to 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

so I have a MacBook Air running 11.2.1 Big Sur

```
pip --version
```

returns this output:

```
pip 20.2.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

when I type python into the terminal, it automatically loads python 2.7, and python3 loads python 3.8.2 like its supposed to

I want to install PyQT5 and this version of pip isn't letting me do that, I want to upgrade pip to pip3 and replace python 2 with python 3 in the process.

Can you guys help me upgrade my python and pip? I don't mind losing python or pip 2 completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `python3` interpreter to run the command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

The `-m` calls the `__main__.py` module of a specified package.

---

> Use `pip3` binary directly:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force pip
```

Valid with: `pip -V`

Comment: ok So, I did this and brew install python3 and pip 3 is installed, how do I make it default to pip3 and python3 now?

Comment: Run this code , `pip3 install --upgrade --force pip` (or) `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip`

Answer (score -1):

for macOs `brew install python3`